# 2 Connected to the router, only one has internet access

Tags: internet-connection

Edited:

I have two win 10 laptops. Both of them are wirelessly connected to the same router. However only one has internet access.

The router actually serves as **Access Point**. That is, it is connected to another "root router" with cable LAN to LAN. This root router is connected to the modem, and serves as the DHCP.

The *Default Gateway* of the working laptop is correct - **10.0.0.138**. This is the root router IP. Its IP is **10.0.0.14**, in the DHCP IP range. 
However, the other one *Default Gateway* is **192.168.1.1**, and its IP **192.168.1.5**).

The router's (AP) IP is 192.168.**2**.1 - different range, as expected.

Looks like the problem is that it is assigned with IP by another DHCP server.

Both windows connection adapters are set to **obtain IP automatically**

As I do not have full access to the network (ie root router
I am not sure the what exactly **192.168.1.1**, the 2nd laptop DHCP, is.

However, I do see him on the "air". Still haven't manage to understand what it is, as I have limited access to the full network.

What can cause that?

Is it possible to bypass the problem temporarily, maybe by forcing the machine to be assigned by the root router?

tx

Comment: Either the two laptops have conflicting IP addresses (unlikely unless you explicitly set it up like that), the router is broken, the laptops WiFi adapter is broken, or the drivers for the laptop are not functioning correctly. There is actually so much that can go wrong that it is simply not possible to tell you exactly what's wrong with the information provided. Try messing around with different devices to connect and update your question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: More information please... at least the IP statuses of the two laptops

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly you gave me insight I should have thought about before. Question revised.

Comment: @RadialApps Question revised